# passing value to ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am working in my first app and i am trying to passing values to ajax function but i don't know how to proceed.

please any help?

this is my code:

html: this is the link which has to pass the value, e.g "9"

```
<a id="btnRockArg" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="category.html">Categor&iacute;as</a>
```

function

```
category: function(){

    function getCategory(valueCatRockArg) {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax({        
            url: 'http://.....org/api/get_category_posts?id='+valueCatRockArg+'&count=5&order=desc',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data){               
                var source   = $("#category-template").html(); //Get the HTML from the template in the script tag
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source); // compilamos la plantilla
                var blogData = template(data); // en data se almacena el contenido que nos viene de wordpress
                $('#category-data').html(blogData); // mostramos el contenido
                $('#category-data').trigger('create');
                dfd.resolve(data);

            },

            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        return dfd.promise();
    };

    getCategory().then(function(data){
        $('#all-categories').on('click','li', function(e){                
            localStorage.setItem('postData', JSON.stringify(data.posts[$(this).index()]));
        });
    });


},
```

thank yoy very much!!

Comment: Use `data` attribute of `$.ajax()` to send data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({        
        url: 'http://.....org/api/get_category_posts',
        data:'id='+valueCatRockArg+'&count=5&order=desc',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){               
            var source   = $("#category-template").html(); //Get the HTML from the template in the script tag
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source); // compilamos la plantilla
            var blogData = template(data); // en data se almacena el contenido que nos viene de wordpress
            $('#category-data').html(blogData); // mostramos el contenido
            $('#category-data').trigger('create');
            dfd.resolve(data);

        },

        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

try this, use data atrribute to pass parameters

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What's the problem with the OP's code and why does your "answer" solve it? Don't play the "spot the difference" game please. **Explain** your answer.

Comment: thank you very much karthick! one think, and the html how to send the value to data?

Comment: @pablo cant get your question

Comment: i am sorry if i didn't explain me very well, my english is really bad and i am new with apps. Karthick my question is, how to to pass the value to "valueCatRockArg"? or how to structure the link in html to send the value to "valueCatRockArg"? thank you again

Comment: var valueCatRockArg=$("selector").val();